# Receive the number of entities entered by the user in DIalogFlow

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I'm trying to get the number of entities entered by the user of a specific entity in DialogFlow, but I did not find any API in the DialogFlow documents that could return that value (an example of what I want: in the fruit entity, if the user types maces, orange, the result returned would be 2).

```
const [Tamanho,Sabores,Rua,Num,NumPizza] = [agent.parameters.Tamanhos, agent.parameters.Sabores, agent.parameters.location, agent.parameters.numberinteger, agent.parameters.numbers];
const Sabtes = agent.parameters.Sabores.value; //It was just a test
  if(Sabores.items.length>4)
     agent.add("Você fez mais pedidos de sabores do que o permitido");

 if(Sabtes>2)
     agent.add("Você fez mais pedidos do que o permitido");
```

Comment: When one defines parameters for an intent, I think one has the opportunity to define the parameter as a list.  If that is the case, won't the parameter passed to your fulfillment / webhook be an array ... in which case you can ask the array for its length?

Comment: I did, I just tried with the "length"(I had tested this, but I think I had spelled it wrong), removing the 'items' and it worked. But thanks for the help.